# Push notification system for Windows 8.1 WPF desktop application

Tags: wpf, windows, notifications, push, desktop

I'm developing a WPF desktop application for Windows 8.1 using Visual Studio Express.
The application has to be installed using ClickOnce on tablets using accounts with no administration privileges.
I need to send push notifications from a web server to the application, and the notifications should be shown even if the application is not executing, as it happens on Android/IOS and Windows Phone.
Unfortunately I can not develop the app as Windows Store application, so I need a suggestion to implement push notifications on desktop.

My first idea was to create a Windows Service, let it receive notifications and show an alert to user. But reading some posts it seems to me that to install a service on Windows I need to use an administration account.

So, how can i get this? Any idea?

Comment: You need to have a process running in order to receive push notifications. It doesn't have to be your main process though, you could create a light-weight executable that would start with the computer, register with your remote push notification service on start up and just receive the notifications and show a pop-up or start the main app if necessary...

Comment: Thank you Dean! I have created a process and set to start at boot using a Windows registry key in LOCAL_USER. This solution seems ok!